# std::vector Semantic issue while using push_back

Tags: c++, vector, stl, constants, std

```
#include <vector>
typedef void (* const MyType)(void *, void *);
static void exampleFunction(void *param1, void *param2)
{
    // ...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::vector<MyType> myVector;
    myVector.push_back(exampleFunction); // fails.
}
```

Here is the code, it seems the line with `//fails` is not compilable.
I comment it out, and there's no problem. But if its open, this is the error I'm getting in XCode:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/memory:1593:27: Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'void (*const *)(void *, void *)'
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it is `const`. STL have some requirements for elements, after all.

Comment: `std::vector` and `const` generally don't play well together.

Comment: One offtopic advise: Try to avoid `void*`. Use templates instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vector (as well as any other standard container) manages the memory for its elements in particular way. Many opperations it is allowed to perform require that element cannot be `const`. For example its `fill_n` method which fills a range with copies of the same value. Or construction of elements using placement `new`:

```
 /**
 * Constructs an object in existing memory by invoking an allocated
 * object's constructor with an initializer.
 */
 template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
  inline void
  _Construct(_T1* __p, const _T2& __value)
  {
    // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
    // 402. wrong new expression in [some_]allocator::construct
    ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(__value);
                     ^
                    // here you would get an error: invalid static_cast
  }
```

There is no such thing like `std::vector` with `const` elements.

---

Solution:

make the pointer non-`const`:

```
typedef void (* MyType)(void *, void *);
```

Comment: Thank you :) this worked like a charm, i didn't know there was such limitation in vectors. I'll kep that in mind, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

For maximum compability in many different compilers, do the following changes:

```
typedef void (*MyType)(void *, void *);
```

^remove const

```
void exampleFunction(void *param1, void *param2)
```

^remove static

```
myVector.push_back(&exampleFunction);
```

^add ampersand

Comment: Thank you for the tips, the first tip solved my issue, and indeed your third tip is really useful, i implemented it in my solution. Thnanks for that,however, with your second tip there is a problem. is it possible to pass non-static functions as parameters? 
Because i thought this is not possible c++, but im no expert. if i remove static , i get this error.

/Users/onatbas/workspace/cpp/example/main.cpp:24:23: Reference to non-static member function must be called

Comment: It was not clear from your code that it was a member function, if it is, it needs to be static (in this context).

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `typedef` to:

```
typedef void (* MyType)(void *, void *);
```

(As a side note, it works well in VS2013.)